# JS: Empty an input field on click with Prototype

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, prototypejs

I originally used JQuery for this project, but now I'm having to use Prototype, and I'd like to take what I've written in JQuery and use it in Prototype.

It's a simple bit of code that empties the search bar when the user clicks on it. I'm sure it's pretty easy to do in Prototype, but I don't know how.

Here's what I wrote for JQuery...

```
    $(window).load(function(){
        $("#search").on("click", function() {
            if ($(this).val() == "search") {
                $(this).val("");
                $(this).css("color", "black");
            }
        });
        $("#search").blur(function() {
            if ($(this).val() == "") {
                $(this).css("color", "gray");
                $(this).val("search");
            }
        });
    });
```

How can I convert the above for use with Prototype?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For anyone who wants to do this in the future, here's what worked for me:

```
$('search').onblur = function() {
  if($('search').value == '') {
    $('search').value = 'search';
$('search').setStyle({color:'gray'});

  }
}

$('search').onfocus = function() {
  if($('search').value == 'search') {
    $('search').clear();
      $('search').setStyle({color:'black'});
  }
}
```

Comment: Conventionally, Prototype scripts would use [`Event.observe`](http://api.prototypejs.org/dom/Event/observe/) to register a handler, which then uses `this` instead of `$('search')` each time. That way you can have multiple handlers for an event, and multiple inputs for a handler.